Wildfly Embedded Artemis in K8s - UnknownHostException
I'm attempting to run Wildfly 26 in K8s. When the second pod comes up it's getting an error:
2024-04-05 13:07:58,239 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (Thread-3 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@4b262fe0)) AMQ224091: Bridge ClusterConnectionBridge@44dbdfc2 [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.my-cluster.c06524ea-f36e-11ee-95d7-4ef5e9f861e4, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.my-cluster.c06524ea-f36e-11ee-95d7-4ef5e9f861e4, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=default], temp=false]@7e873458 targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl (identity=(Cluster-connection-bridge::ClusterConnectionBridge@44dbdfc2 [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.my-cluster.c06524ea-f36e-11ee-95d7-4ef5e9f861e4, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.my-cluster.c06524ea-f36e-11ee-95d7-4ef5e9f861e4, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=default], temp=false]@7e873458 targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=http-connector, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?httpUpgradeEndpoint=http-acceptor&activemqServerName=default&httpUpgradeEnabled=true&port=8080&host=msg-email-jay-test-0], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]]::ClusterConnectionImpl@2015267711[nodeUUID=e793336e-f36e-11ee-82cb-9ed7cde89c14, connector=TransportConfiguration(name=http-connector, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?httpUpgradeEndpoint=http-acceptor&activemqServerName=default&httpUpgradeEnabled=true&port=8080&host=msg-email-jay-test-1, address=jms, server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=default])) [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=http-connector, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?httpUpgradeEndpoint=http-acceptor&activemqServerName=default&httpUpgradeEnabled=true&port=8080&host=msg-email-jay-test-0], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]] is unable to connect to destination. Retrying
2024-04-05 13:07:58,723 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] (Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@4b262fe0)) AMQ214016: Failed to create netty connection: java.net.UnknownHostException: msg-email-jay-test-0

My messaging-activemq configuration is the default from standalone-ha.xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:13.1">
    <server name="default">
        <security elytron-domain="ApplicationDomain"/>
        <cluster password="${jboss.messaging.cluster.password:CHANGE ME!!}"/>
        <security-setting name="#">
            <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
        </security-setting>
        <address-setting name="#"
                         dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ"
                         max-delivery-attempts="${jboss.messaging.redelivery.maxAttempts:800}"
                         redelivery-delay="${jboss.messaging.redelivery.delay.initialMillis:500}"
                         max-redelivery-delay="${jboss.messaging.redelivery.delay.maxMillis:5000}"
                         redelivery-multiplier="${jboss.messaging.redelivery.delay.multiplier:2}"
                         max-size-bytes="10485760"
                         page-size-bytes="2097152"
                         message-counter-history-day-limit="10"
                         redistribution-delay="1000"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
        </http-connector>
        <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-connector>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
        </http-acceptor>
        <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-acceptor>
        <jgroups-broadcast-group name="bg-group1" jgroups-channel="activemq-cluster" connectors="http-connector"/>
        <jgroups-discovery-group name="dg-group1" jgroups-channel="activemq-cluster"/>
        <cluster-connection name="my-cluster" address="jms" connector-name="http-connector" discovery-group="dg-group1"/>
        <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
        <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" consumer-window-size="${jboss.messaging.consumer.buffer.bytes:0}"/>
        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector" ha="true" block-on-acknowledge="true" reconnect-attempts="-1" consumer-window-size="${jboss.messaging.consumer.buffer.bytes:0}"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
    </server>
</subsystem>

and my jgroup is setup for DNS_PING
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jgroups:8.0">
    <channels default="ee">
        <channel name="ee" stack="tcp" cluster="ejb"/>
    </channels>
    <stacks>
        <stack name="tcp">
            <transport type="TCP" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp"/>
            <protocol type="dns.DNS_PING">
                <property name="dns_query">${rave.messaging.cluster.dns.query}</property>
            </protocol>
            <protocol type="MERGE3"/>
            <protocol type="FD_SOCK"/>
            <protocol type="FD_ALL"/>
            <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
            <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK2"/>
            <protocol type="UNICAST3"/>
            <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
            <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
            <protocol type="MFC"/>
            <protocol type="FRAG2"/>
        </stack>
    </stacks>
</subsystem>

msg-email-jay-test-0 is the name of the other (original) Pod, but I would expect any name lookup to include the governing service domain e.g. $(podname).$(governing service domain)
As is I don't know where the host name is coming from.

The name is coming from the initial pod and the cluster topology: basically you are connecting to your pod1 which is connected to pod0 vai the cluster connection. Then you get the cluster topology (aka node0 and node1) and it can't resolve the node0 name

So how do I specify the node names so that they include the headless service name instead of just the pod name, or connect by IP instead of name since the jgroup has the IPs from the DNS_PING?
